# How to end on first async parallel task completion in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async.js

I have a list of tasks that I want to run in parallel using https://github.com/caolan/async.

I want the program to proceed (probably through a callback) after the *first* of these parallel tasks is complete, not all of them. So I don't think the naive

```
async.parallel([task1, task2], callback)
```

works for me.

Alternatively I could spawn two tasks and cancel the incomplete one, but I can't figure out how to do that using async either.

Thanks!
-Charlie

Comment: `async` cannot cancel a task once it's started it; after that, it can only wait for it to finish or ignore it. The ability to cancel would have to reside with the task or the object that owns it. Something akin to [`XMLHttpRequest`'s `.abort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#abort()).

Comment: That fact means I have to try a different approach - thanks for the info!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Parallel Race

You can get `async` to initiate the final callback by returning an `error` that evaluates as `true` but isn't actually an error.

I've put together an example that uses `-1` as an error code.  In the final callback I check the `error` value and if it's not `-1` then it's an actual error.  If the error value is `-1` then we'll have a valid value in `results`.  At that point, we just need to remove extra elements from `results` of the other async functions that have not completed yet.

In the below example I've used the `request` module to pull html pages and the `underscore` module to filter the results in the final callback.

```
var request = require('request');
var _ = require('underscore');

exports.parallel = function(req, res) {
  async.parallel([
    /* Grab Google.jp */
    function(callback) {
      request("http://google.jp", function(err, response, body) {
        if(err) { console.log(err); callback(true); return; }
        callback(-1,"google.jp");
      });
    },
    /* Grab Google.com */
    function(callback) {
      request("http://google.com", function(err, response, body) {
        if(err) { console.log(err); callback(true); return; }
        callback(-1,"google.com");
      });
    }
    ],
    /* callback handler */
    function(err, results) {
      /* Actual error */
      if(err && err!=-1) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
      }
      /* First data */
      if(err===-1) {
        /*
         * async#parallel returns a list, one element per parallel function.
         * Functions that haven't finished yet are in the list as undefined.
         * use underscore to easily filter the one result.
         */
        var one = _.filter(results, function(x) {
          return (x===undefined ? false : true);
        })[0];
        console.log(results);
        console.log(one);
        res.send(one);
      }
    }
  );
};
```

## Remaining Function Results

When you setup `async#parallel` to work like this you won't have access to the results of the other asynchronous functions.  If you're only interested in the first one to respond then this isn't a problem.  However, you will not be able to cancel the other requests.  That's most likely not a problem, but it might be a consideration.

Comment: Nice solution, thanks for the code Daniel! Unfortunately the two tasks I was trying to run are large, so it's computationally expensive to let the ignored one finish. I will probably end up breaking the tasks into smaller chunks, so that I can spare the wasted cycles of either letting it finish ignored (like this design) or just waiting for both to finish.

Answer (score 1):

The [async.parallel](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel) documentation says:

> If any of the functions pass an error to its callback, the main callback is immediately called
>   with the value of the error.

So you could return an error object from *all* of your parallel functors, and the first one to finish would jump you to the completion callback. Perhaps even your own special error class, so you can tell the difference between an actual error and a "hey I won" error.

Having said that, you would still have your parallel functions running, potentially waiting for callbacks to complete or whatever. Perhaps you could use `async.parallelLimit` to make sure you're not firing off too many tasks in parallel ?

Having said all that, it's possible you are better served by trying another method from the async library for this task - firing off parallel tasks then having these tasks race each other may not be the best idea.